# Rails 4 Form Requires Page Reload to Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a shopping cart for my rails 4 app, and I need to refresh the page after I update items in my cart, in order for changes to be reflected.

The models in questions, are `line_items`, and `shopping_carts`. Each shopping cart has multiple `line_items`, which belong to a single `shopping_cart`. I am able to successfully add `line_items` to my `shopping_cart`. However, when I try to update the quantities of the `line_items` from my `shopping_cart` show page, the `line_item`'s database record gets updated properly, the `shopping_cart` show page reloads (per the route I have set), a successful flash message of the action appears, HOWEVER, the quantity of my `line_item` has NOT been updated. If I then go ahead and refresh the page, the quantity updates accordingly. I'd love to understand why this is happening and how it can be prevented so on one new page load the quantities which are correct in the `line_items` database table, show properly on the `shopping_cart` show page (I have a suspicion the issue is being caused by viewing records for one table, in a different controller, but I don't know why).

Sidebar: I'd prefer not to use Ajax.

*shopping_carts_controller.rb*

```
class ShoppingCartsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        $shopping_cart = current_cart
        ...
    end

end
```

*line_items_controller.rb*

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  end

  ...

  def update
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])

    if @line_item.update_attributes(line_item_params)
      flash[:success] = "Quantity was successfully updated."
      redirect_to shopping_cart_path(current_cart)
    else
      flash[:failure] = "Quantity not updated."
      redirect_to shopping_cart_path(current_cart)
    end

  end

  ...

  private

  def line_item_params
    params.require(:line_item).permit(:quantity)
  end

end
```

*application_controller.rb* - for current_cart method

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

after_filter :store_location

def store_location
  # store last url as long as it isn't a /users path
  session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath unless request.fullpath =~ /\/users/
end



private

def current_cart
    ShoppingCart.find(session[:shopping_cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

    shopping_cart = ShoppingCart.create
    session[:shopping_cart_id] = shopping_cart.id
    shopping_cart
end

end
```

*shopping_carts/show.html.erb*

```
    <% for item in $shopping_cart.line_items %>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-6 columns cart-item">
                <%= item.meal.name %> 
            </div>
            <div class="small-3 columns cart-item text-center">
                <%= simple_form_for item do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :quantity , :label => false, :label_html => { :class => 'form-label' } %>
            </div>

            <div class="small-3 columns cart-item text-right">
                <%= number_to_currency(item.total_price) %>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="small-3 columns text-center">
                    <%= f.button :submit, "UPDATE", class:"button tiny secondary" %>
                <% end %>
            </div>

        </div>

    <% end %>
```

Comment: eep, what is this awful global variable you are using? `$shopping_cart` ? change that to `@shopping_cart` at once! :) Not sure if it'll fix your problem (it might), but you should never, ever, ever need to use global variables in Rails. (certainly not like this).

Comment: Read my mind, @TarynEast

Comment: Perhaps also changing your `for loop` to: `<% @shopping_cart.line_items.each do |item| %>` would be better too

Comment: @TarynEast sorry about that! i need '$shopping_cart' available to three different controllers so I was using a global, sounds like that's not good practice :) i tried changing them all to '@shopping_cart' but it errors out saying line_items isn't a known attribute for shopping_cart in my show view.

Comment: @patrick thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately still the same issue :(

Comment: I'd need to see more about what current_cart is. Not being able to access @shopping_cart from other controllers may indicate either issues with the associations or how you're setting the instance variable.

Comment: @patrick just added the current_cart bit from the application controller. thanks for taking a look!

Comment: You don't need `$shopping_cart` for that. stick the `id` of the shopping cart into the session, and have a `before_action` in each of your controllers that instantiates it fresh each time. You really, really must not use global variables.

Comment: wait, you're already doing that with current_cart... so why do you need `$shopping_cart` at all? just use `@shopping_cart = current_cart` in each of the controllers you need it for... and you're good to go

Comment: Yeah I'd try what @TarynEast suggested. Move the `@shopping_cart = current_cart` to each of the controllers you need it in. Perhaps use a before_action to keep it DRY?

Comment: @TarynEast @patrick i've made the change but now any page with *@shopping_cart.line_items* references, returns the error "undefined method `line_items' for nil:NilClass". wasn't the case when I was using *$shopping_cart.line_items*. will keep investigating but am I missing something basic?

Comment: In the past, I've done this with a before action like @patrick suggested. I would set the instance variables in the method itself (`@shopping_cart = Cart.find(...); rescue @shopping_cart = Cart.create(); session[...]=...`), then just add a before filter to your controller (`before_action :current_cart`). That way, the instance variable should be available to you for any controller.

Comment: That's an elegant solution @Lee.

Comment: Yes - but you should fix that problem by properly setting up `@shopping_cart` in a `before_action` ... not by trying to use a global variable (which may persist old, broken wrong data between actions like happens in your original question) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue to my primary problem of needing to refresh to see the results.

Instead of redirecting to the 'shopping_cart_path' in the line_items controller after an update, I tried redirecting to 'shopping_cart_url' and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

From the discussion above, it seems like your issue is likely with how @shopping_cart (or $shopping_cart) is being defined. I figured I'd write my suggestion up as an actual answer.

In the past, I've done this with a before action like @patrick suggested. I would set the instance variables in the method itself, then just add a before filter to your controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :current_cart

  # ...

  private

  def current_cart
    @shopping_cart = Cart.find(session[:current_cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @shopping_cart = Cart.create
    session[:current_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
  end

end
```

That way, the instance variable should be available to you for any controller.

---

If you only use @shopping_cart in a few controllers, I'd put it in a concern instead and only include it where needed:

app/controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb:

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

  def set_current_cart
    @shopping_cart = Cart.find(session[:current_cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    @shopping_cart = Cart.create
    session[:current_cart_id] = @shopping_cart.id
  end
end
```

And then, in any controller that needs your @current_cart variable, put the following

```
class RandomController < ApplicationController

  ##### THESE TWO LINES #####
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_current_cart, only: [:index, :new, :create] # or whichever actions you need
  ###########################

  def index
    # @shopping_cart should be set for use here
    # ...
  end

  def destroy
    # because of the only: [...] statement, @current_cart isn't valid here
    # ...
  end

  # ...

end
```